# how to replace substitute string in cloudbuild.yaml

Tags: bash, google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

how to replace substitute string in cloudbuild.yaml?

I want to set appengine version as $TAG_NAME with cloudbuild. Since the version only accept hyphen, I need to replace the dot to hyphen first.

I tried:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', '--no-promote', "--version=$(echo $TAG_NAME | sed 's/[.]/-/g')"]
timeout: '1600s'
```

But got

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) argument --version/-v: Bad value [$(echo 0.0.1a4 | sed 's/[.]/-/g')]: May only contain lowercase letters, digits, and hyphens. Must begin and end with a letter or digit. Must not exceed 63 characters.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I end up with the solution

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    version=$TAG_NAME
    gcloud app deploy --version=${version//./-}
  entrypoint: bash
```

Comment: Any insight on how to replace / with _ ?

Comment: @g.lahlou Add a backslash before the slash like `${version//\//_}`